# Как заменить подстроку в строке начиная с первого совпадения и до конца строки?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Только начинаю изучать регулярные выражения.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как заменить подстроку в строке начиная с первого совпадения и до конца строки

```
str = "Первый тест скоро планирую закончить";
str.replace(new RegExp("/тест$/",'g'),"релиз");
```

**UDP** До конца строки заменить означает, что мне нужно получить в результате "Первый релиз"

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew я писал, что нужно удалить часть до конца строки, т.е. мне нужно так "Первый релиз". По вашему совету получается так:
"Первый релиз скоро планирую закончить"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первый аргумент в `new RegExp("/тест$/",'g')` — это *шаблон*, второй аргумент – *флаг(и)*. Использование разделителей в шаблоне — ошибка, так как `new RegExp("/тест/",'g')` найдёт `/тест/` в тексте, но не `тест`.

Кроме того, `$` требует конца строки **в данной позиции**, чтобы найти текст до конца строки, его нужно "найти", то есть использовать `.*` (если в строке нет переносов строки) или `[^]*` / `[\w\W]*` (если есть символы переноса строки).

К тому же необходимо результат замены присвоить переменной, иначе замена будет произведена впустую.

```js
var str = "Первый тест скоро планирую закончить";
str = str.replace(/тест.*/, "релиз");
console.log(str);
// => Первый релиз
```

Comment: cпасибо за пояснение работы `RegExp`, но на выходе мне нужно получить не "Первый релиз скоро планирую закончить", а "Первый релиз"

Comment: "$ требует в данной позиции конца строки" да, именно до конца строки мне и нужно. Заменить только одно вхождение до конца строки

Comment: @Вася $ - это в буквально "конец строки", но в строке до конца ещё много символов. Чтобы регулярка их поймала, надо искать `тест.*` (точка совпадает с любым символом, * - совпадает много раз)

Comment: @Lyth спасибо! То, что нужно!

Comment: @Lyth а если заменить не до конца строки, а к примеру до первого встречного символа `&`  или любого другого?

Comment: Ага. понял - вот так `str = str.replace(/тест.*&/, "релиз");`

Comment: @Вася Нет, если до первого вхождения, то `str = str.replace(/тест.*?&/, "релиз");` / `str = str.replace(/тест[^&]*&/, "релиз");`.